# jQuery Show/Hide Bootstrap Modal During Dataload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a bootstrap modal message while jQuery is re-freshing data into a couple of my DIVs (and then hide it).The data is refreshing OK. However, the modal flashes on and off instantly.

This is also the case when I just use a simple loader GIF image instead of the modal. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The modal (or gif) needs to remain in place until the data is fully refreshed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.container').on('click', '.markAttend', function(event, ui) {
   myApp.showPleaseWait(); //this calls the modal to display
   event.preventDefault();
   var contactID =  $(this).attr('contactID');
   var eid = <?php echo $eid ?>;

   $.ajax({
      url: 'functions-ajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'action=markAttend&contactID=' + contactID + "&eid=" + eid, //send a value to make sure we want to destroy it.
      success: function(data){
         $("#searchlist").load(location.href + " #searchlist"); //Refresh list
         $("#attendanceTotal").load(location.href + " #attendanceTotal"); //Refresh list
         $("#searchinput").val(''); //clear out search input field
         myApp.hidePleaseWait(); //this calls the modal to hide
      }             
   });
 });
```

Comment: can you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to wait until `load()` functions are done.

For that you need to add a callback like this:

```
$("#searchlist").load(location.href + " #searchlist", function(){
   myApp.hidePleaseWait();
});
```

BUT, since you have 2 `load` functions, need some more complex logic. Try with this:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.markAttend', function(event, ui) {
   myApp.showPleaseWait(); //this calls the modal to display
   event.preventDefault();
   var contactID =  $(this).attr('contactID');
   var eid = <?php echo $eid ?>;
   var counter = 0;

   $.ajax({
      url: 'functions-ajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'action=markAttend&contactID=' + contactID + "&eid=" + eid, //send a value to make sure we want to destroy it.
      success: function(data){
         $("#searchlist").load(location.href + " #searchlist", function(){ 
            counter++;
            if(counter === 2) myApp.hidePleaseWait(); //this calls the modal to hide
         }); //Refresh list
         $("#attendanceTotal").load(location.href + " #attendanceTotal", function(){ 
            counter++;
            if(counter === 2) myApp.hidePleaseWait(); //this calls the modal to hide
         }); 
         $("#searchinput").val(''); //clear out search input field

      }             
   });
 });
```

I'm not able to test it, so let me kwow

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.